# How do I edit BLOBs (containing JSON) in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, json, oracle, blob, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do I edit BLOBs (containing JSON text) in Oracle SQL Developer?

I can open and view them, but do I need an external editor to edit them? Any help on what to use, even if just notepad, and how to go about it would be greatly appreciated in the answer.

*EDIT: BLOBs in question contain JSON text.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you run a query in SQL Developer 3.1 (and probably earlier releases) that returns a BLOB, you can double-click on the particular BLOB you're interested in where you'll be prompted either to try to send the data to an external editor or to try to have the built-in SQL Developer display control attempt to interpret the data as an image or as text.  Your JSON data will probably display correctly if you choose the text option.

If you want to change the data, however, you're going to have to issue an `UPDATE` to actually set the data.  SQL Developer doesn't have the functionality to directly edit the LOB data.  For example

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET column_with_json_data = 
          utl_i18n.string_to_raw( '{"foo": {"id": "1", "value": "2"}}' )
 WHERE primary_key = <<some value>>
```

will update the specified row with the new JSON data encoded using the database character set.  If you want to store the data in some other character set, `string_to_raw` takes an optional second parameter that specifies the character set.  So if you want to store the data using the UTF-8 character set, you'd do something like this

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET column_with_json_data = 
          utl_i18n.string_to_raw( '{"foo": {"id": "1", "value": "2"}}', 'AL32UTF8' )
 WHERE primary_key = <<some value>>
```

Of course, since JSON data is textual, you'd be far better off storing the data in a CLOB which is designed to store character large objects.  Then SQL Developer (and other tools) could just display the text rather than requiring you to select the result and then take additional actions to convert it to text.  And you wouldn't have to convert the data to `RAW` in order to update the data in the database.

If the data is too long for `string_to_raw` to handle (which depends on the character set and the data but will occur any time the `RAW` data exceeds 2000 bytes), you can store the data in a `CLOB` and then convert that into a `BLOB` that you use to update the table.  That's a bit more complex but it is more flexible.  In this example, I'm padding the JSON data out to 3200 characters with a '*'-- obviously the test data is no longer valid JSON but that's not important for purposes of this question.

```
declare
  l_blob        blob;
  l_clob        clob := rpad('{"foo": {"id": "1", "value": "2", "name": "bob"}}',3200,'*');
  l_amt         integer := dbms_lob.lobmaxsize;
  l_dest_offset integer := 1;
  l_src_offset  integer := 1;
  l_csid        integer := dbms_lob.default_csid;
  l_ctx         integer := dbms_lob.default_lang_ctx;
  l_warn        integer;
begin
  dbms_lob.createTemporary( l_blob, false );
  dbms_lob.convertToBlob( l_blob,
                          l_clob,
                          l_amt,
                          l_dest_offset,
                          l_src_offset,
                          l_csid,
                          l_ctx,
                          l_warn );

  -- You'll want to add a WHERE clause as well
  update json_data
     set data = l_blob;

  dbms_lob.freeTemporary( l_blob );
end;
/
```

Comment: Ok, I edited the BLOB and have the text I wish it was. How do I perform the `UPDATE` with this text file? Connect me here and I'll know how to do it all!

Comment: @MatthewDoucette - Updated my answer with an example of the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: awesome. Let me try her out!!

Comment: it seems to work but I am now getting this error, if you can help me out with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743084/how-can-i-avoid-raw-variable-length-too-long-errors-in-sql-developer It relates to this question if you wish to add it to your answer. Thanks sooo much.

Comment: this is odd as the text I am using is only 2,368 characters long, not breaking the 4,000 byte limit. Makes me wonder what is setting off the `raw variable length too long` error. Thanks so much for this solution however.

Comment: @JusticCave, why are you using `rpad` for (at all)?

Comment: I had to set the rpad length to the exact length of the text I was inserting, but it worked!

Comment: @MatthewDoucette - You shouldn't need to use `RPAD` at all.  I was just using it to create a 3200 character string since I was too lazy to type a valid 3200 character long hunk of JSON.

Comment: @MatthewDoucette - Actually, I was mistaken-- the maximum length of a `RAW` is 2000 bytes, not 4000.  Updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: createTemporary creations are dropped at the end of the script, I assume? It's so obvious, but I just wanted to double check.

Comment: @MatthewDoucette - They are freed when the local variable goes out of scope.  I added a call to `dbms_lob.freeTemporary` at the end of the script just for good code hygiene.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking to change individual blobs without having to write any SQL, you can do this in Oracle SQL Developer:

1. Double click on the cell that says `(BLOB)`. An edit button (pencil for an icon) should appear to the right side of the cell. Click on it.
2. Click `Download`, to the right of **Saved Data**. Save it somewhere.
3. Edit the file in whatever program you want. Save.
4. Back in the Edit Value dialog of Oracle SQL Developer, click `Load`, to the right of **Local Data**. Find the file wherever you saved it after editing. Click `OK` in the Edit Value dialog now.
5. Click the `Commit Changes` button if you're satisfied with your changes, or the `Rollback Changes` button if you've changed your mind.

Much easier, I think, than doing the whole `dbms_lob.convertToBlob` if this is just a quick one-off thing.

Comment: Why sometimes the 'Load' link and whole 'Local Data' session is disabled? What is the criteria to enable those buttons?

Comment: @zion Perhaps you're in a query results pane? Changing data is only possible when opening the table and going to the _Data_ tab (though I don't understand this limitation.) See [BLOB load unavailable (greyed out)](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/comment/12964754/#Comment_12964754).